# haskell : stack install hfmt error

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm totally new in haskell, and trying to install hfmt using stack.

```
stack install hfmt
```

but it shows

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for hfmt-0.2.0:

  hindent-4.6.4 must match ==5.* (latest applicable is 5.2.5)
  hlint-1.9.35 must match ==2.* (latest applicable is 2.0.15)
  stylish-haskell-0.6.1.0 must match ==0.8.* (latest applicable is 0.8.1.0)

needed for unknown reason - stack invariant violated.
```

So, I tried to re-install hindent , hlint and stylish-haskell again.
However I couldn't find any command - `stack upgrade` or `stack update`.. even I failed to remove these packages.

Could you help install/update these package?

Answer (score 3):

With reports like this, it's best to include the output of `stack --version` to know what version of the tool you're using. Also, *how* you installed Stack can be useful information.

As for `hfmt`: there's no version of it present in a Stackage snapshot, which you can see here:

https://www.stackage.org/package/hfmt

On my machine, I was able to build successfully against LTS 10.3, using this command:

```
stack install hfmt-0.2.0 --resolver lts-10.3
```